# Why am I getting the error "cannot find -lncurses"?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, ncurses

I have just started a university course in C and we have been instructed to run a makefile through Cygwin (which uses the GCC compiler), however I have very little knowledge about computers and am out of ideas as to how to solve this. When I run the makefile it says:
`cannot find -lncurses`.
I understand ncurses is a library and the compiler is looking for it as some of the files in the makefile need it, but I don't understand how it is missing, where it is, or how I point the compiler to it. Can anyone offer me any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You need aditional packages.

From https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2001/msg00124.html

> The ncurses package has been updated to ncurses-5.2-7. ncurses is a 
>   package that provides character and terminal handling libraries, 
>   including 'gui-like' panels and menus.  It is often used instead of
>   termcap.
>
> MAJOR CHANGES to the ncurses package:
>
> 1. The ncurses package has been split into three separate packages:
>        ncurses-5.2-7     (contains the static libs, header files,
>                           man pages, etc)
>        libncurses6-5.2-2 (contains the new DLL's)
>        terminfo-5.2-1    (contains the terminfo database)
> 2. libncurses5-5.2-1 is a new package containing the old
>        DLLs from ncurses-5.2-5, for backward compatibility.
> 3. ncurses is now built using the 'auto-import' features of
>        recent binutils.
> 4. ncurses-5.2-5a    if it's necessary to rollback, this package
>                          contains the files from ncurses-5.2-5
>                          (post splitup) Thus, this package +
>                          terminfo + libncurses5 = old ncurses-5.2-5.
>
> See NOTES below for additional information.
>
> INSTALLATION:
>
> To update your installation, click on the "Install Cygwin now" link on
>   the http://cygwin.com/ web page.  This downloads setup.exe to your
>   system.  Then, run setup TWICE and answer all of the questions EACH
>   TIME. The FIRST time, update ONLY the ncurses package.  The SECOND
>   time,  install the terminfo, libncurses5, and libncurses6 packages. 
>   You MUST  do BOTH steps.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. The odd thing is I have had the program working before and everyone else is just working out of a batch file, with no Cygwin actually installed.

Comment: Then something changed in your libs path. Try `-lncursesw` instead of `-lncurses`

Comment: See I don't know how to do that. I am just trying to run the make file, which I assume does that for me. Is there a way I can edit the libs path?

Comment: Edit the makefile and change `-lncurses` with `-lncursesw`, then run again the makefile.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! That worked. I don't understand why I was able to use ncurses last week and all of a sudden need ncursesw now, but I'm happy I can move on.

Comment: You are welcome, and yes, I had the same problem some time ago and the reason was (apparently) a replacement of the lib from other instalation updating ncurses to the wide version.